# preg_match does not work with php, utf8?

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-match

I have a string coming from a Wordpress database, and want to replace the text with youtube video if it matches my code.

Something like this:

```
text bla [youtube video="cCaW6sdAkEkd9PY"] bla bla and some more text

$pattern = '/\[youtube video="(.+)"\]/';
```

It does not match on data coming from the database but it matches on a string if I use output from `var_dump` and test on that.

I believe it has to do with utf-8 but i do not know hot to fix it i have tried `/u`, `utf8_decode` and so on, but no result.

Comment: IMHO you should add some backslashes before '[' and ']'

Comment: Your YT video ID is not valid :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no UTF-8 in your text. The problem is that you didn't escape the square bracket `\[`

```
 $pattern = '/\[youtube video="(.+?)"]/';
```

(It's sufficient to escape only the first. The meta purpose of the closing bracket is ignored.)

Comment: But escaping just one of them gives me the same effect as an unmatched parentheses... *shivers*